# .mov split with iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, split, .mov

Is something like this possible? I searched a lot but the ways I found are on mac os.

What I want to do is split a video to many videos so each file will have smaller size.

Can anyone guide me through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in bacground using AVFoundation:

[Trimming and transcoding a movie](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH7-SW8)

You can also do this using the trimming UI:

[UIVideoEditController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: splitting a large video is possible?

Comment: @iTroyd23 As long as the format is supported, I don't see why not. The app should only load part of the frames at a time.

Comment: So we cant even trim a big video file, say 40 mins?

Comment: @iTroyd23 I only tried by using ffmpeg some time ago, and it went well. Using `AVFoundation` shouldn't be much different, it will just take longer for larger video files. Using `UIVideoEditController` you can only trim video chunks up to 10 minutes length, according to their documentation, but it should be possible to trim from videos of 40 minutes or longer.

Comment: @alex-i thank you. I will try `UIVideoEditController`.

Comment: my problem is to upload a large video to youtube. I want to spilt the video with out user Knowlegde. how can make with out `UIVideoEditController`?

Comment: @iTroyd23 you can use `AVFoundation`, which doesn't show any UI by itself. See "Trimming and Transcoding a Movie" section from the link above.